# Svnant enable logging

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

We are using SVN ant task for exporting project from SVN on Linux

```
<target name="export-from-svn">
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <export srcUrl="${svn.url}" destPath="path" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

Previosly it worked fine without any error. Nothing has been changed, however now it is stucked without any error or warnings. Is there any way to enable more verbose output. If I execute command manually "export -r HEAD ..." it works fine.

```
export-from-svn:
      [svn] Missing 'javahl' dependencies on the classpath !
      [svn] Using svnkit
      [svn] <Export> started ...
      [svn] export -r HEAD https://from /home/to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be attributes to enable more verbose logging in the `svn` tasks. You can try launching the Ant buildfile using `ant -verbose ...`. But since you're saying the task is "stuck", then you may want to take a thread dump of the process to check the state of the threads in the JVM. You can locate the Ant build as a Java process and run `jstack <pid>` to dump the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem so leaving what worked for me in case someone else has the same issue.

After spending hours trying to debug the svnant task and then finally looking at the thread dump of the svnant task, noticed that the thread is stuck while establishing a ssl connection. The corresponding java.exe process in the task manager is spinning but it doesn't throw any errors.

To resolve, go to the svn server settings and change the settings to allow the deprecated SSL 3.0 protocol in addition to the TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. Please note that this is not recommended because of the obvious security risks that come with using older protocols. But if your ant client is old and until you get a chance to update your client (strongly recommended for security reasons) then allowing the older protocols in svn server will get the svn ant tasks working again.